# Closing Select Windows in C#

Tags: c#, forms, window, hide

I have two forms, first one is a login window and once the correct details are entered I have it show the other window and hide the current.

Question is I want to not only hide the first form but close it without going near the second main form. I don't know if it makes a difference during debugging but when I am testing the application is won't stop debugging until I stop it manually as clicking the x or close button won't work as the first app is still running only hidden.

### Code

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUsername.Text == "admin" && txtPassword.Text == "1234")
            {
                formMain main = new formMain();
                main.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct Username and Password.");
            }
        }
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `this.Close()` in place of `this.Hide()`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you'd have to do is `this.close` as `Main` is closing to close the login form.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the program file, where your login form is called.

Call ShowDialog, then enter your main screen only if the user successfully logged in.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay in answering. I've tried this.close(); it just closes the whole program before I even get to the main.

Hi Brad how do you mean? (Call ShowDialog, then enter your main screen only if the user successfully logged in.)